# Django form saving issue AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, forms

I've been tried many different things to solve this issue and none seem to work.

Essentially I am just trying to create a registiration page which contains 2 forms built from 2 models, the User model and my restaurant model (profile model). Every time I submit my form, I keep getting  AttributeError 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'. I thought it may have been my cuisine many to many field causing the issue as its the only thing that is a tuple I think. So I tried removing the cuisine aspect altogether but that didn't work. Heres my code. I can provide additional information if necessary. Appreciate any help very much

Traceback - [dpaste.com/2CXS7MZ](http://dpaste.com/2CXS7MZ)

**Additional Information**

```
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth/register/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\testapps\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response, line 30
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\testapps\Scripts\python.EXE
Python Version: 3.4.1
```

**Models**

```
class Cuisine(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=False)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

#User Profile (The restaurant)
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    #Main Test Field
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25, blank=False)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cuisine = models.ManyToManyField(Cuisine, blank=True)
    approved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #Non Essential Fields
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**Forms**

```
class UserSignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)

class RestaurantForm(forms.ModelForm):
    cuisine = forms.ChoiceField(queryset=Cuisine.name.all())
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        exclude = ('user', 'approved',)
```

**Views**

```
def restaurant_register(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponse('Thank you for registering.')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserSignUpForm(request.POST)
        restaurant_form = RestaurantForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and restaurant_form.is_valid():
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            profile = restaurant_form.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user
            profile.save()
            profile.save_m2m()
            return render(request, '/auth/login.html')
        else:
            return user_form.errors, restaurant_form.errors
    else:
        user_form = UserSignUpForm()
        restaurant_form = RestaurantForm()
    return render(request, 'auth/register.html', {'restaurant_form':restaurant_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

**Template**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
        <form id="user_form" method="post" action="/auth/register/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ user_form.errors }}
            {{ restaurant_form.errors }}
        {% csrf_token %}
            {{ user_form.as_p }}
            {{ restaurant_form.as_p }}
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
        </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**URL**

```
url(r'^register/$', views.restaurant_register, name='register'),
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback.

Comment: Here you go http://dpaste.com/2CXS7MZ , is that what you meant? If not This was the whole thing -----
C:\Python34\testapps\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in get_response
                response = middleware_method(request, response) ...

C:\Python34\testapps\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py in process_response
        if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:

Comment: If the forms are valid, best practice is to return a `HttpResponseRedirect`. This way it's less likely that the user will (accidentally) repost the form data, most likely resulting in an error message even though the user is signed up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a `HttpResponse` here:

```
return user_form.errors, restaurant_form.errors
```

return this instead:

```
render(request, 'auth/register.html', {'restaurant_form':restaurant_form, 'user_form': user_form})
```

or rather, you should skip that whole else and return.

Comment: Yes, delete that whole else block and let it fall through to the last line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:
`return user_form.errors, restaurant_form.errors`
You returning tuple instead of a response